# terraform: Add an OS user with a given public key

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I have created an EC2 instance on AWS using terraform;

What I want is to add a user in the OS level and provide a particular key to be added in its `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

The [`aws_instance`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/instance.html) documentation does not seem to list this functionality.

Is there a way to go about this?

**edit**: I think a way to do this is via the [`remote-exec`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html) provisioner, but then again since I have already created my ec2 resource I need a way to force-run this;

Comment: Terraform isn't really best setup for this kind of work. If you want a user with an SSH key available on an instance the best approach is always to bake that into the image using something like Packer. Going from best to worst here you can also use user data to configure your instance on start up after creation, use a provisioner to run when the instance is created or use a null resource based provisioner to always run every time Terraform runs. If you already have an instance set up and don't want to replace it then just treat this as a one off and do it manually.

Comment: That was some really useful feedback, many thanks; I am trying to run a `remote-exec` provisioner as test on a new instance and getting: `* aws_instance.to-delete: Failed to upload script: please login as the user "ubuntu" rather than the user "root".` It is an ubuntu ami; any idea why this is happening? where should I instruct the `remote-exec` provisioner as what user to log in to the machine?

Comment: You need to use the `ubuntu` user as it states. Direct root logins are disabled by default.

Comment: Yes but how do I instruct `remote-exec` provisioner to do so? Nothing relevant mentioned here: https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/remote-exec.html

Comment: Connection details are listed at https://www.terraform.io/docs/provisioners/connection.html because other provisioners also need to know how to connect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer given by @Brandon Miller seems to be nice, I ended up with the following (not very elegant, I must admit):

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
        "sudo adduser --disabled-password --gecos '' myuser",
        "sudo mkdir -p /home/myuser/.ssh",
        "sudo touch /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys",
        "sudo echo '${var.MY_USER_PUBLIC_KEY}' > authorized_keys",
        "sudo mv authorized_keys /home/myuser/.ssh",
        "sudo chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser/.ssh",
        "sudo chmod 700 /home/myuser/.ssh",
        "sudo chmod 600 /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys",
        "sudo usermod -aG sudo myuser"
   ]

    connection {
     user     = "ubuntu"
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 10):

Following up on comments and edits, what you are looking for might look like this:

```
resource "aws_instance" "default" {
  ...
  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo useradd someuser"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("yourkey.pem")}"
    }
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "authorized_keys"
    destination = "/home/someuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("yourkey.pem")}"
    }
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "sudo chown someuser:someuser /home/someuser/.ssh/authorized_keys",
      "sudo chmod 0600 /home/someuser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
    ]

    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "ubuntu"
      private_key = "${file("yourkey.pem")}"
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

- Create the user
- Upload your authorized keys file
- Set the appropriate permissions on the file for the user

You could also do this all in one `remote-exec` depending on how you want to handle setting up the `authorized_keys` file

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, best is to bake such config in the AMI.

But for some temporary/dev work, another way is to use the EC2 UserData block:

```
data "local_file" "public_ssh_key" {
  filename = "/path/to/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"
}

resource "aws_instance" "sample" {
  ...
  user_data = <<-EOF
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo -u ubuntu bash -c 'echo "${data.local_file.public_ssh_key.content}" >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
    EOF
  ...
}
```